# Sort Column Total

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

I have a view with column totals.

What I want is to sort the totals-column in a Xpages-view or repeat-control.

I am able to get the totals to display but cannot sort them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are those totals per category? Does it mean, you want to sort categories? If so, are the categories multilevel?

Comment: the question needs clarification. there are no columns in a repeat?

Comment: @Frantisek Kossuth

Yes, the totals are per category, and I want to sort the totals without losing the categorization.

There is an categorized view. Category is for example Company name. In the view is a column with totals, so the category has also a total. The wish is that this categorized view will show the company category, who has the highest total at the top of the view, without losing the categorization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very clean. I wouldn't do that in production - for performance reasons - it's a brute force solution, but it should work for fair amount of categories (up to few hundreds).

Assume the view can be used for category lookups (similar to show single category). Then all you need is list of categories in correct order - based on totals and not alphabetical order. Therefore, in first cycle, loop through all categories (use NotesNavigator with cache) and store them as pair of values - (category, totals). It may be Map[String,Double]  or Set[Category] where Category is POJO with category and totals attributes. In both cases you will need your own Comparator. If your categories are hierarchical, use only top level category (sorting of tree structure is more complicated).

For example:

Australia (5)

Brazilia (10)

Chile (7)

will sort as

Brazilia (10)

Chile (7)

Australia (5)

Cache this collection in viewScope (assuming totals are "static" for short period of time, user will need to reload the page to get updated data).

Feed this collection to repeater with simple data table (or view or repeater) showing only selected category.

GUI will be a bit odd with pagers (pager for categories and pager for content of category), but you will handle this, I hope.

Comment: Thanks for this proposal. I'm going to try soon.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably better to ask can this type of sorting or resorting be done in Notes rather than can it be done in XPages. If it can be done in Notes then you should be able to do the same in XPages - sometimes automatically. 
XPages can only do so much with the view datasource. So if the datasource can't sort the categories by the totals then you won't be able to do this in XPages. At least not out of the box.
You might be able to do something with repeats - doing a lookup of the datasource, retrieving all documents under a certain category that has the highest total before moving on to the next category in the sequence - but it likely to become pretty complicated and not worth it in the end.
Sorry if it's not the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Paul thank you for your reaction. No, it isn't the answer I looking for :-) 
I had this question for a couple of weeks and couldn't find a solution. It isn't possible in the Notes Client that's for sure. I spoke Frank van der Linden (my collegue) and he suggest to try it in XPages. After trying it in a view-control and repeat-control my conclusion was: it isn't possible in XPages.
That's why I asked this question here if anyone has ideas for a solution, because it remains a challenge for me to solve!

Answer (score 0):

I will try to clarify it.
There is an categorized view. Category is for example Company name.
In the view is a column with totals, so the category has also a total.
The wish is that this categorized view will show the company category, who has the highest total at the top of the view, without losing the categorization